# select records when field or joined field is matched

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to select when a field matches, or if a joined table field matches:

users table:

```
---------------------------
|user_id |job_title  |age |
---------------------------
|1       |hardware   |22  |
|2       |software   |45  |
---------------------------
```

experience table:

```
-------------------------
|id |user_id |job_title |
-------------------------
|1  |1       |random    |
|2  |2       |random    |
|3  |2       |hardware  |
-------------------------
```

I need a query that will return both users when job_title is 'hardware' from either table...

```
SELECT
    user_id u
FROM
   users
JOIN experience e ON e.user_id = u.user_id AND e.job_title LIKE '%hardware%'
WHERE
   u.age > 18 AND
   u.job_title LIKE '%hardware%'
```

Comment: `JOIN experience e ON e.user_id = u.user_id AND e.job_title = u.job_title`?

Comment: Can you generalize your question?  What would be the logic if there were 4 users in the two tables?

Comment: Tim - what do you mean?  It shouldn't matter how many users there are... I need to select each user where their age is > 18 and their job_title is like 'hardware'...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Based on your question only one of job_title has to be "hardware"?

```
SELECT user_id u 
FROM users u left join experience e
   on e.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE u.age > 18 AND 
      (u.job_title  LIKE '%hardware%' OR e.job_title LIKE '%hardware%')
```